# Python Parallel Computing - Scoop

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, linear-regression, python-scoop

I am trying to get familiar with the library Scoop (documentation here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/scoop/0.7/scoop.pdf) to learn how to perform statistical computations in parallel, using in particular the futures.map function.

As such, at first, I would like to try to run a simple linear regression, and assess the difference in performance between serial and parallel computations, using 10000000 data point (4 features, 1 target variable) randomly generated from a Normal Distribution.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from scoop import futures
import statsmodels.api as sm
from time import time

def linreg(vals):
    global model
    model = sm.OLS(y_vals,X_vals).fit()
    return model
    print(model.summary())    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    random.seed(42)
    vals = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc = 3, scale = 100, size =(10000000,5)))
    vals.columns = ['dep', 'ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3', 'ind4']
    y_vals = vals['dep']
    X_vals = vals[['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3', 'ind4']]

    bt = time()
    model_vals = list(map(linreg, [1,2,3]))
    mval = model_vals[0]
    print(mval.summary())
    serial_time = time() - bt

    bt1 = time()
    model_vals_1 = list(futures.map(linreg, [1,2,3]))
    mval_1 = model_vals_1[0]
    print(mval_1.summary())
    parallel_time = time() - bt1

    print(serial_time, parallel_time)
```

However, after that the regression summary is indeed produced in serial - via the Python's standard map function - an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\bootstrap__main__.py", line 302, in 
>       b.main()
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\bootstrap__main__.py", line 92, in main
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\bootstrap__main__.py", line 290, in run
>       futures_startup()
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\bootstrap__main__.py", line 271, in futures_startup
>       run_name="**main**"
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\futures.py", line 64, in _startup
>       result = _controller.switch(rootFuture, *args, **kargs)
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop_control.py", line 253, in runController
>       raise future.exceptionValue
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop_control.py", line 127, in runFuture
>       future.resultValue = future.callable(*future.args, **future.kargs)
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
>       pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
>       mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>     File "Scoop_map_linear_regression1.py", line 33, in 
>       model_vals_1 = list(futures.map(linreg, [1,2,3]))
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\futures.py", line 102, in _mapGenerator
>       for future in _waitAll(*futures):
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\futures.py", line 358, in _waitAll
>       for f in _waitAny(future):
>     File "C:\Users\niccolo.gentile\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorenviron\lib\site-packages\scoop\futures.py", line 335, in _waitAny
>       raise childFuture.exceptionValue
>   NameError: name 'y_vals' is not defined

is produced afterwards. This means that the code stops at `model_vals_1 = list(futures.map(linreg, [1,2,3]))`.

I have also tried running it with map both times and indeed the error does not appear.

I also specify that the script has been correctly launched with:

```
python -m scoop Scoop_map_linear_regression1.py
```

from Anaconda Prompt command line.

Indeed, should it be launched without the -m scoop parameter, it would not be parallelized and would actually run, but just using two times the built in Python's map function, as how you would get reported in the Warnings. That is, without specifying the -m scoop parameter when launching it, futures.map would be replaced by map.

My goal is instead to run it in parallel, using exactly futures.map, and assess the performance improvement.

Specifying it to avoid any other similar answer and a consequent put on hold.

Any comment is highly appreciated and welcome.

Comment: When I made size=1000 your code ran to completion on my laptop, no errors.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. I have actually tried with size=1000, but I'm still getting the same error. Did you launch it from the command terminal using the same parameters? If yes, may ask you to tell me if parallel_time < serial_time and if the two regression outputs are equal (e.g. R Squared, Adj. R-Squared, F-Statistic et cetera)? Thank you.

Comment: Output below as an answer, as comments do not allow formatting.

Comment: My reply to your request for test output was deleted.

Comment: Dear Phillips, I saw your reply yesterday, but can reply only now. You, indeed, had not run the command with the -m scoop parameters, which means that scoop was not launched. Hence, you just run two times the Python's built in map function (as specified in the Warnings you got), which indeed in my question I said was already not bugging. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way, @JamesPhillips, since my question is indeed still relevant, how can such put on hold status be removed?

Comment: The "hold status" message states that this question was voted "off topic", so that in effect the hold status can never be removed.